# Как работает интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно сабж: как изнутри работает данный интерфейс? Что происходит при вызове метода `NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)`? Как UI элемент узнает, что что-то произошло и нужно "перерисоваться"? Объясните пожалуйста. Чем подробнее - тем лучше)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если вы имплементируете интерфейс [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), то вы должны определить `event` [`PropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), и отправлять его каждый раз, когда значение изменится.

Если у вас есть привязка к какому-то свойству, то `Binding` в числе прочего проверяет, реализует ли binding source (то есть, объект, к свойству которого происходит binding), этот интерфейс, и если да, то подписывается на этот самый `event`. По приходу event'а значение свойства перечитывается (через reflection).

---

Дополнение: А что происходит с `ItemsSource`? А для него интересен интерфейс [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), который сообщает о том, что в коллекции появились/исчезли элементы.

Если вы привязываете `ItemsSource` в `ListView` к коллекции, `Binding` заботится о том, чтобы `ListView` знал текущее значение самой коллекции. То есть, если вы коллекцию подмените на другую коллекцию, об этом сообщит Binding. А вот нотификация об изменении *списка элементов* коллекции происходит следующим образом.

Когда `ListView` видит, что объект коллекции поменялся (эту информацию поставляет `Binding`), он самостоятельно проверяет наличие интерфейса `INotifyCollectionChanged`, и если коллекция его поддерживает, подписывается на событие [`CollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Когда это событие приходит, в нём есть [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), который содержит информацию о том, что именно произошло, какие элементы добавились (и куда), а какие исчезли (и откуда). Имея эту информацию, `ListView` может перестроить список.

Заметьте, что обыкновенный `List<T>` не реализует интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`, поэтому если в привязке лежит `List<T>`, `ListView` автоматически обновляться не будет. Обычно никто не реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged` самостоятельно, а пользуются готовыми коллекциями. Например, [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Можно еще немножко конкретики? Взять, например, `ListView`, который бандит из `List<t>`. Когда один из элементов `List<t>` изменяется, вызывая событие `PropertyChanged`, то `ListView` обновляет конкретно этот элемент, или же обновляет весь визуальный список?

Comment: @AlexD.: Добавил.

Comment: Весьма познавательно, благодарствую!

Comment: @AlexD.: Спрашивайте ещё, у нас на сайте много специалистов :)